# Inner sub-selects in ContentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to use inner subselect statement in a Query using content provider?
Ex.:

`SELECT * from foo where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from foo)`

If yes, can anyone please tell me how to send it to in "selection/selectionArgs" ?

Thnx in advance...

BTW, i cannot use rawquery

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative would be to put a raw query into your content provider and have it called by a specific CONTENT_URI that executes only the raw query.

Comment: I'm using a RAW query with a content provider.  The trick is the where is the sql that you want to use, where you can still use a ? for selection arguments and pass the arguments as normal.  Here a code snippet here I call the content provider.  'code'  String[] selectionArg = new String[] { selectedRule };
  ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
  mGroupCursor = cr.query(
    /* URI */         TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RAWQUERY,
    /* projection */  null, 
    /* where */       TDAdb.RAWQUERY_INDEX,
    /* arguments */   selectionArg, 

                /* sort order */  null);'code'

Comment: My content provider and db activities for this are at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282800/android-search-not-returning-results-after-suggestion-chosen[link]